# Freeform select field - setting the default "selected" value

Tags: solspace-freeform, forms

I'm developing a form with Solspace Freeform Pro edition.
I didn't use the composer but coded the form myself.
I succesfully mapped a SELECT being defined as Newline Delimited in Solspace backend.
What if I want to make one of the entries the SELECTED one when rendering the template tag?
I've tried this:

```
{freeform:field:country_select attr:selected="France"}
```

with no success.